# Python - Upload file to Google Team Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to a specific Team Drive via the Python API, but am struggling with where to specify the teamDriveId. I'm working with Drive v3.

Here is the function I am working with:

```
def upload_file(self):
    # self.service: Google Drive Hook - works well for other functions
    # self.drive_id: Id of Team Drive I am trying to upload to

    metadata = {'name': 'sample.txt'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('sample.txt', mimetype = 'text/plain')
    upload = self.service.files().create(body=metadata, 
                                         supportsTeamDrives=True,
                                         media_body=media,
                                         fields='id).execute()
```

I have attempted to put this in both the `create()` function and the `metadata` JSON as `{'parents': self.drive_id}` but this either return an `Unexpected keyword argument: teamDriveId` or the file will just upload to my personal drive.

I do not have any folders inside the Team Drive I am attempting to work with. I looks like I could set `{parents': <teamDrive_folderId>}` but I am hoping to find a solution where I don't have to specify a folder and can just put files in the root of the Team Drive.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `parents` to the Team Drive's ID works for me and inserts the file into the root of the Team Drive. Minimal example:

```py
# media is a `MediaFileUpload` instance
service.files().create(
    supportsTeamDrives=True,
    media_body=media,
    body={
        'parents': ['0AILoX...'],  # ID of the Team Drive
        'name': 'foo.txt'
    }
).execute()
```

Are you sure that you got the right ID?

Comment: Definitely the right ID. Looks like the issue was I was not passing the DriveId in a list. Works now, thanks!

Comment: Great answer! It works for me, as well. But what if I have a folder inside that TeamDrive? What should I pass / set to upload into the folder within a TeamDrive? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should just be able to use the folder's ID in the `parents` list. Didn't test it, though :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was trying to use the Golang package to upload files with a service account... I'm not exactly sure where they were going before I started supplying this field - but they were definitely going somewhere. Supplying the teamdrive ID in the parents property put the files where I expected.